# How to create a custom number format in Excel to show comma as decimal separator

Tags: excel

E.g. instead of `4,100.3` (American) it would be `4 100,3`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to  `Tools - Options - International Tab (or Advanced if using Office 2010) - Separators` (uncheck "use system separators" - and put in what you want as separators.

Comment: Any alternative without changing this setting for the whole application?

Comment: Can't say for sure. Frankly I've not researched for it as I never had the need.