# How do I make the numbers in my formula comma style?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=IF(M13<0,"Your account is in credit of "&+(-M39)&" you do not have to make any payments.","Your account balance is $"&+M39&" Please make your payment to cover the balance by the due date." )

This is my formula I have in a cell. How do I make the number comma style?

Comment: use [TEXT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)

Comment: `=TEXT(M39,"0,000")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom number format in Excel to show comma as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904063/how-to-create-a-custom-number-format-in-excel-to-show-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

> =IF(M13<0,"Your account is in credit of "&TEXT(-M39," #,##0.00")&" you do not have to make any payments.","Your account balance is $"&TEXT(M39," #,##0.00")&" Please make your payment to cover the balance by the due date." )

"#,##0.00" denotes comma format.